# Multiple instances of same activity?

Tags: android, instance, android-activity

I have some problem with my application,
I have 4 buttons, one to start each of the other activities.
Say activity is called a,b,c,d. I want to be able to change between this activities without getting 100ds of paused activities in the stack but still save the back history.

I.e a->b->a->c->d->a where all a is the same instance of the activity

So practically what I want is to be able to restart the very same instance of the activity instead of starting a new one.

Possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, It is possible.

```
mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

Add this flag to your intents, this will bring your activity on top of stack rather than creating new one.

Comment: unfortunately does the back history disappear, otherwise it works, but will not fit this solution

Comment: Yes, this is the right answer.  Not (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) or (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TASK);

Answer (score 0):

If your activity "a" is your home, you can add these flags:

```
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Then, when you press back, the application will exit (because you cleared all others activities) => [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

Comment: this is not what i'm looking for, want to be able to start the activities any number of times and still back between all four, no one of them is home

Comment: Then I guess when you have to save your instancesStates and activities order in a stack, and reorder_to_front each time you want to change your activity. Hope this will helps you